# Расход ресурсов при поддержке нескольких экранов в Android

Tags: android, ресурсы

Если поддерживать несколько экранов в андроид приложении, то размер памяти занимаемой приложением будет резко возрастать.
Некоторые приложения выкладываемые на Андроид Маркет имеют размер "зависит от устройства". Это означает, что при установке не все ресурсы будут "установлены" или что при закачке не все будут выкачиваться, а сам Андроид Маркет даст только необходимые ресурсы для устройства.
З.Ы. Сам не являюсь пользователем Андроид, но начинаю программировать под них потихоньку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер зависит от устройства всего лишь означает, что разработчик для разных устройств сгенерировал разные APK и больше ничего. Я тоже иногда так практикую - скажем какая-то функция под одну версию Android'а есть, а под другую нет - приходится писать несколько веток исходников под разные версии Android'а.

Ну а ресурсы используются строго только те, которые нужны в данном девайсе, ненужные ось не будет загружать - в предыдущем сообщении это все показано.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду поддержку приложением нескольких размеров-разрешений экрана, то расход ресурсов из тех, что реально потребляются во время работы, мало зависит от числа поддерживаемых модификаций. Если имеются в виду ресурсы, устанавливаемые на устройство (иконки, картинки и т.п.), то их действительно может быть суммарно много по размеру, но опять же используются только те, что используются. Как написано в документации - [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html):

> At runtime, Android uses uses the appropriate resource based on the current configuration. For example, you might want to provide a different UI layout depending on the screen size or different strings depending on the language setting.